# Angular Routing and RxJs subscription sharing

Tags: angular, rxjs

Edit: apparently the `shareReplay` approach works fine too. I don't understand why however, given the description of the operator. If someone is so kind to explain why, it will be much appreciated.

---

I currently have a `Component`, managed via routing, with a template that looks like

```
<app-one [attr]="entity$ | async"></app-one>
<app-two
  [attrOne]="(entity$ | async)?.id"
  [attrTwo]="(entity$ | async)?.name"
></app-two>
```

---

The `Component` code is

```
export class EntityComponent implements OnInit {
  entity$: Observable<Entity>;

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.entity$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      map(params => params.get('entityId')),
      mergeMap(entityId => this.service.getEntity(entityId))
    );
  }
```

---

Being that I use the `async` pipe three times, the `service.getEntity` is called three times (I can see three HTTP calls).

How can I mitigate this problem?
Is adding `shareReplay(1)`

```
this.entity$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  map(params => params.get('entityId')),
  mergeMap(entityId => this.service.getEntity(entityId)),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

an acceptable solution? I don't think so, as it will mess up routing.

Edit: my components are all `OnPush`, and subscribing and storing the result as a class property would mean having to `detectChanges`, which I don't like at all.

Comment: One option is to subscribe to the `this.route.paramMap` and storing the result on an entity property (in this case entity will not be of type observable). Another option is to unwrap the observable value to a local template value using ngIf: `*ngIf="(entity$ | async) as entity"`

Comment: @Igor for example, when the routing parameter changes, won't it simply use the previously calculated value?

Comment: When the routing parameter changes wouldn't the component be reloaded on thus a new call to `ngOnInit`?

Comment: @Igor no, apparently the `Component` isn't recreated (if you use Angular routing).

Comment: @Igor `shareReplay` seems to work fine, even if the component isn't reloaded, I don't know why honestly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could wrap your two components with a `ng-container` applying the `async` pipe and store the result in a variable and then use that in the components, something like:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="entity$ | async as entity"
    <app-one [attr]="entity"></app-one>
    <app-two
          [attrOne]="entity?.id"
          [attrTwo]="entity?.name"
    ></app-two>
</ng-container>
```

**Update**
What I mean is that you are able to do something like:

```
this.entity$ = new Observable<Entity>(observer => {
    observer.next(null);
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
        map(params => params.get('entityId')),
        mergeMap(entityId => this.service.getEntity(entityId)),
    ).subscribe(e => {
        observer.next(e);
        observer.complete();
      }, () => {
        observer.complete();
      });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! What if I'd like to show those template components even when the value isn't still there? I mean, `*ngIf` will hide them until the first valid value is emitted, right?
Another option I considered is `subscribe`ing and storing the result as a class property. However my components are all `OnPush`, so I'd have to `detectChanges`, which I don't like.

Comment: @LppEdd you should update your question to include this info: "my components are all OnPush, so I'd have to detectChanges, which I don't like."

Comment: You could create your own `Observable` and emit a first value `null` then subscribe to the `paramMap` and give the value from the service or `null` if an error happens

Comment: @dcg mmmh, I think I got it, but I'm not an Angular/RxJs expert. Could you maybe show a little snippet which demonstrate it? Doesn't need to be detailed, just a sketch.

Comment: @LppEdd I edited my answer. Haven't test it but I've done things like that before.

Comment: @dcg thank you! Just so that you know, I tested very well the `shareReplay` approach, and it seems it works fine! I don't know why however. I will mark your answer as accepted anyway.

Comment: @LppEdd Good to know the `shareReplay` approach!